# Jquery UI panel resizing on click

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

I am using Jquery Ui panels.([http://code.google.com/p/ist-ui-panel/][1])

While loading the application, everything is fine like collasible, draggable etc.

But i want to make the panel collapsible while clicking on some links.fo ex:

This code will run when the form is loading....

```
$('#myNews').panel({
    'collapsible' :true,
    'stackable':false,
 });
```

The html

```
<div  class="panel" id="myNews" >
<h3>Poll</h3>
<div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

I want to make 'collapsible' :false when clicking some link.... like this

```
$('#click1').click(function() {
   $('#myNews').panel({
      'collapseType':'slide-right',
      'collapsible':false,
    });
});
```

the code is running without any error, but the '#myNews' not getting affected when clicking the '#click1' link.

Need some help pls.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm the one behind ist-ui-panel, and Jesse was right — by now the only way for you is to use 'destroy' method somewhat like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click1').bind({
        'click': function() {
            $('#myNews').panel('destroy');
            $('#myNews').panel({
                'collapsible' :true,
                'collapseType':'slide-right',
                'stackable':true
            });
        }
    });


    $('#click2').bind({
        'click': function() {
            $('#myNews').panel('destroy');
            $('#myNews').panel({'collapsible': false});
        }
    });
});
```

Notice, you should explicitly destroy previous panel before making a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the uncompressed source code](http://idlesign.narod.ru/ui-panel/ui.panel.js) for that widget, it appears that what you are doing is only meant to be used to create panels, not to modify them afterward.

The underlying software is either buggy or I don't understand it. So you'll have to hunt down some bugs, but you can **use the 'destroy' method** on that widget to reset the div completely, and **then make it a panel again**, like so:

```
$('#myNews').panel("destroy");
$('#myNews').panel(...
```

As I said, it's buggy or I don't quite get it - there's an error raised by the destroy call which you have to catch, and subsequent calls to make new panels do make panels, but they aren't completely correct.